# PhP PDO exec() doesn`t creates tables

Tags: php, pdo, exec

I am new to PhP , and i am  kind of stuck with this problem : i have a database created end when i try to use PDO exec() to create a table nothing happends , no table is created, no error message is displayed .I tryed validating my code online and got no error.Please help.Thanks.

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';

try{
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host = $host ; dbname = $db", $user , $pass);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book(
id INT(20) NOT NULL UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
autor VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)";
$connect->exec($sql);
$connect = null;
}catch(PDOException $e){
$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO query fails but I can't see any errors. How to get an error message from PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990858/476)

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with PDO and exec. You need to learn proper SQL prior running it via PHP.

Comment: No doubt i need to learn a lot , so maybe you could inlight me with some of yours vaste knoledge ...

Comment: I have the same problem and my SQL statement is absolutely correct. If you have a solution to this problem, please post it. It will help others with same issues

Answer (score 0):

In your catch block, you're not actually doing anything with the exception message. Try changing

```
$e->getMessage();
```

to

```
echo $e->getMessage();
```

and see if that shows you any errors.

Comment: We have a compulsive downvoter out there?

Comment: thanks for the tip , still nothing ...no error mesage, no table created ....